# Hbase : how to handle NotServingRegionException during region split

Tags: hbase

During region splits my client call fails with this exception.
However the exception returned is

```
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: NotServingRegionException: 1 time,
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$500(AsyncProcess.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.getErrors(AsyncProcess.java:897)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:2346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.batchCallback(HTable.java:814)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.batch(HTable.java:793)
```

In this the action is NotServingRegionException. I was thinking to retry in this case with some sleep but RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException can come in any case not just region split.

How can I handle this case ? 
Should I retry if action contains this notservingregion exception ?

Comment: I dont know whether you have implemented your pre-splits correctly... Thats why I m giving a pointer... go through http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/  specially HOW REGION SPLITS ARE IMPLEMENTED